# How to display the image from JSON object string

Tags: android, json, image

Im new to android..

Im facing a problem in app..

I've been trying several ways of displaying my JSON images but my solutions never succeeded.

In my database the images are stored in a folder. So in my JSON object i got the scr path for image. Now i want to display the image in emulator.I got the path in my JSON object like this : "imgsrc=question/images/u2_1_l2_q66". I have stored the path in imgarr array.

How to display the image from this path? I want to add the images folder to drawables.Please help me. Thanks a lot.

> code

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
    Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
    try {
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    if (success == 1) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
        System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
         for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
        JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
        String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
        System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
        ques1.add(question);
        String img = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
        System.out.println("Checking ::"+img);
        imgarr.add(img);
         }
    } else {
        showAlert();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
}
return null;
}
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
    imgarr=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(imgarr));
    TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
    txtque.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(j) + imgarr.get(g));
       }
```

Comment: Please any help me to solve my problem. Really i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> In my database the images are stored in a folder

After you have full path to file, just pass wrapped File Object to BitmapFactory, and display Bitmap in ImageView

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
{
 try 
 {
//you might want to downscale it....
  return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
 {
  //throw exception
 }
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image data, decode and then show. I suggest you use a library such as  [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).